# smoothDivScroll only loops one time

Tags: jquery, laravel, plugins

```
<div id="logoParade">
  <div class="scrollingHotSpotLeft" style="display: none;"></div>
  <div class="scrollingHotSpotRight" style="display: none;"></div>
    <div class="scrollWrapper">
      <div class="scrollableArea" style="width:1147px;">
         <a id="startAtMe" href="#"><img src="{{ URL::to('img/dentalnews/ourPartners/ad.jpg') }}"></a>
         <a href="#"><img src="{{ URL::to('img/dentalnews/ourPartners/bio.jpg') }}"></a>
         <a href="#"><img src="{{ URL::to('img/dentalnews/ourPartners/espe.jpg') }}"></a>
         <a href="#"><img src="{{ URL::to('img/dentalnews/ourPartners/philips.jpg') }}"></a>
         <a href="#"><img src="{{ URL::to('img/dentalnews/ourPartners/dcn.jpg') }}"></a>
         <a href="#"><img src="{{ URL::to('img/dentalnews/ourPartners/dental-corp.jpg') }}"></a>
         <a href="#"><img src="{{ URL::to('img/dentalnews/ourPartners/robert-hill.jpg') }}"></a>
         <a href="#"><img src="{{ URL::to('img/dentalnews/ourPartners/noble.jpg') }}"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried doing it in other projects and it works well. But when I used it in my project and placed it in the footer.php of laravel 4.2 it only loops once. The scripts is implemented well and css is ok as well. What seems to be the problem?

Using smoothDivScroll plugin. Do you guys have a jquery plugin for image slider that loops automatically?

Comment: there are many image slider jQuery plugins... try http://bxslider.com/ or http://www.jssor.com/

Comment: I already solved the problem. But thank you for your time good sir. bxslider is the first one that i used but it does not follow the design guidelines for our project.

Comment: oh glad you solved the issue :)